# How to collect (tabular) data on responsive page?

Tags: responsive-design, dom-traversal

Is it possible to convert responsive table to CSV or Excel ?

Made IIFE [Responsive2CSV.js](https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/Responsive2CSV.js) which works **almost perfect** on a page I want to convert frequently.
[image]

Wanted list marked by blue lines here (not all levels have different border).

It is based on my similar [Convert pdf to html files ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526800/convert-pdf-to-html-files-using-node-js-and-pdf-js/64541404#64541404) answer.

Is there any **better or general way** to convert recursive responsive elements to **simplest** human readable **matrix**(-s) ?

It would be better to keep master blocks together, but how to estimate main parent of a block - somewhere there is DIV with 2 line DIVs inside, all the time a lot of recursive DIVs around...

My IIFE processing logic:

- traverse all text elements, move to parent as long as there is only child, continue as long as innerText is same (sometimes there are hidden parts) and create unique list.
- if next element top = previous bottom merge them with new line between
- **sort** the list **2D** (**by Y**, if Y difference <= 1px **by X**), compare center of boxes.
- create TAB/LF separated list, if x < previous X or y > previous Y break line else break column by TAB